# Understanding SplitChunksPlugin integration with Webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm fairly new to webpack and I'm looking to make some optimizations. Currently I'm using the SplitChunksPlugin to split out shared node_modules.

```
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commons: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: "vendors",
                chunks: "all"
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently I have two entry points 
entry: { one: "./one-main.js", two: "./two-main.ts" },

So in my dist folder I now get a dev.vendors.bundle.js.

When I reload the browser, I can see that one-main.js and two.main.js have reduced in sized significantly. However i also need to include the dev.vendors.bundle.js in my html file and the size of that file offsets any savings I have made on the other two files.
My understanding (which may be wrong) is that the two bundles should have release hashes (in the file name) in prod (so will not be cached by the browser). However the content of node_modules is unlikely to change and so dev.vendors.bundle.js should not have a release hash and therefore will be cached by the browser. Is this correct or am I way off the mark? I have read several tutorials but still cannot wrap my head around it!
Any help would be appreciated.